# strip() does not replace all \n

Tags: python, strip

I'm trying to remove all `"\n"` in this string. However the `string.strip()` method does not entirely clean the text

```
body = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSome text\n\nHow toremovealln?\n\t\t\t\t\tbecause notworking\n\t\t\t\t\t"
body.strip("\n")
```

The result is

```
"Some text\n\nHow toremovealln?\n\t\t\t\t\tbecause notworking\n\t\t\t\t\t"
```

How to remove them all ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `strip` only strips out leading and trailing characters

Comment: So how exactly do you need your ouput ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string.replace` to replace '\n' for '' (empty string):

```
body = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSome text\n\nHow toremovealln?\n\t\t\t\t\tbecause notworking\n\t\t\t\t\t"
print(body.replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: @J.Doe, could you demonstrate that? It's much more surprising for `replace()` to not work (despite documentation saying it should), as opposed to `strip()` not working for a purpose that contravenes its docs.

Comment: Can you test those two lines of code and give me the output? Worked for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have '\n' and '\t' to be replaced by '' and ' ' respectively. So you can use

```
     body1 = body.replace("\n",'')
     body2 = body1.replace("\t",' ')
```

Comment: `body.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "")` one liner will also look good :)

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`string.replace()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_replace.htm) not `strip`:

This method will replace the old `char` with a new `char`. In your case, you want to 'replace' the `new line` `'\n'` with nothing `''`. As seen below

`body.replace('\n', '')`

this will return a new `string` which you can re-assign to body:

`body = body.replace('\n', '')`

now `body` is:

`'Some textHow toremovealln?\t\t\t\t\tbecause notworking\t\t\t\t\t'`

so if you finally want to remove the `tabs` `'\t'` you can just do a further `string.replace()` on them as you said above:

`body = body.replace('\t', '')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the *duplicate* line feeds, you can use a regex through [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(r'([\n])\1+', '', body))
```

Or to remove them all:

```
re.sub(r'\n', '', body)
```